# List gains extra element when passed to function/List index out of range

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list. As soon as I create it, the result of `print list` is:

```
[1, 3, 5, 60, 72, 83, 120, 180]
```

It is then passed as an argument to a function. In the first line of that function (no changes to the list have been made) it is passed to another function. Printing the list here results in the following:

```
[1, 3, 5, 60, 72, 83, 120, 180]
[]
```

Again, this is before anything else has been done. The second function is:

```
def median(li):
    print li
    lenli = len(li)
    if lenli%2==0:
        i = (((lenli/2) + (lenli/2 + 1)) / 2)
        print i
        return li[i]
    else:
        return l[lenli/2 - 1]
```

Once the program gets to `return li[i]`, it throws this error:
    IndexError: list index out of range

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I have tried accessing other elements of the list (0,1) and the same error is still thrown.

EDIT:
The first function is:

```
def binarysearch(target, tosearch):
    print tosearch
    i = median(tosearch)
    while(i != target):
        if i < target:
            del tosearch[i:len(tosearch)]
        else:
            del tosearch[0:i]
        i = median(tosearch)
    return True
```

EDIT2
An example input is this list of numbers, `[1, 3, 5, 60, 72, 83, 120, 180]`, as the source list and the int `5` as the target. The first call of `median()` should then return `72`, and subsequently the median of each shortened list as it is called in `binarysearch()`. Eventually `binarysearch()` should return True.

Comment: Could you show us the first function?

Comment: `return l[lenli/2 - 1]` should be `return li[lenli/2 - 1]` You left of the `i` on `li`. But this is not the reason you have problems.

Comment: Can you give an example input, and what the output should be? (show us the flow the program should have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went over your code. And did some small modifications:

```
def median(li):
    if not len(li)%2:
        i = (((len(li)/2) + (len(li)/2 + 1)) / 2)
        return i, li[i]
    else:
        return i, li[len(li)/2 - 1]

def binarysearch(target, tosearch):    
    while True:
        idx, med = median(tosearch)
        if med == target:
            return True
        elif med < target:
            tosearch = tosearch[idx:]
        elif med > target:
            tosearch = tosearch[:idx]

l = [1, 3, 5, 60, 72, 83, 120, 180]
print binarysearch(5, l)
```

Results in:

```
>>>
True
```

---

I am not going to fix every aspect of your code, but this should get you in the right direction. Good luck.